# python: can't delete open file from os.execl'd python script on windows

Tags: python, windows, file, operating-system

Consider `delfoo.py` and its partner, `lol.py`:

```
#----delfoo.py-----
import os
os.unlink("foo.txt")

#----lol.py----
import os,sys

f = open("foo.txt","w")
f.write("HI")
#not closing f on purpose!
os.execl(sys.executable, sys.executable, "delfoo.py")
print "If this line shows, then something is broken."
```

Invoking `python lol.py` yields (note the last line did not print):

```
C:\tmp>python lol.py

C:\tmp>Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "delfoo.py", line 2, in <module>
    os.unlink("foo.txt")
WindowsError: [Error 32] The process cannot access the file because it is being
used by another process: 'foo.txt'
```

I find this weird, since `os.excel` is supposed to **replace** the currently running process with another one. If it is replaced, and if after a program terminates one can delete the file even if it wasn't closed:

```
C:\tmp>del foo.txt

C:\tmp>dir foo.txt
 Volume in drive C has no label.
 Volume Serial Number is 1060-E78D

 Directory of C:\tmp

File Not Found
```

then why can't I delete the file from the new process that has replaced the previous one? How can I make it so the `os.execl`d instance, `delfoo.py`, can unlink the file opened by its progenitor, `lol.py`, without closing said file?

Comment: im also curious if this would behave the same on linux. not curious enough to try it myself, but curious enough to give an upvote for it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to close the file handler:

```
#----lol.py----
import os,sys

f = open("foo.txt","w")
f.write("HI")
f.close() # HERE !
os.execl(sys.executable, sys.executable, "delfoo.py")
```

Comment: i know.. it's a carefully contrived example. is there a way to do it without closing the file? (last 4 words of my question). the answer will always be 'better book keeping is better', but i am curious.

Comment: No, because when you executes the delfoo.py, the lol.py is still executing with the file open. You can open it again after calling delfoo.py if it's your problem.

Comment: @Claudiu, the `del foo.txt` command doesn't work fine. You just invoke it after the python script. When the python script terminates, the file is closed automatically anyways.

Comment: @Tarantula: no. if i put 'print HI' after the 'os.execl', it'll never print HI - os.execl *replaces* the current process, and therefore i find it curious the previous processes file handlers are still open

Comment: @funktku: the original program stops running when i do `os.execl` - it gets replaces. i thought doing this might leave the file open forever, but i ran the `del` command to show that wasn't the case. why, after the 2nd process finishes, can i delete, but not after the 1st process finishes? ill update question to show why im asking this

Comment: Claudiu, are you sure that your print isn't show because of the WindowsError exception ?

Comment: @Claudiu: Now I understand your question and wonder the answer too.

Comment: this was the only way i could see to do it in the end

Answer (score 0):

Just checking the [os.execl*()](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#process-management) gave me this:

> The current process is replaced
>   immediately. Open file objects and
>   descriptors are not flushed, so if
>   there may be data buffered on these
>   open files, you should flush them
>   using sys.stdout.flush() or os.fsync()
>   before calling an exec*() function.

I am guessing, along with not flushing the file objects, they are not closed as well.

Comment: hmm i saw that too, wasn't sure if flushed referred to closing, i guess it does.. is there any way to actually do it though besides keeping track of my file descriptors?

Comment: From what I understand of exec functions, they replace the environment of the current process with the new process. So any file handles belonging to the environment stays open. Whenever you try to unlink the file, it gives an error because the file handle is actually open in the environment of the new process. So I guess, you have to close all file handles yourself before replacing the environment with a different process.